# Not retrieving set of values from table. Laravel

Tags: mysql, laravel-5

I'm trying to get values from my linking table sfees with columns student_id and mfee_id. Here, there might be multiple student_id with different mfee_id. The thing is that, i want to retrieve all mfee_id with same student_id. 
I have used following syntax, but it is only returning single value:

```
public function verify($id,$sid)
{

 $sfees = sfee::where('student_id', $sid)->value('mfee_id');//trying to get only mfee_id
 return $sfees;
}
```

How can i solve this problem?

//edited
My table looks like:
[image: table format and values]

Comment: Try  $sfees = sfee::select('mfee_id')->where('student_id', $sid)->value('mfee_id')->get();//trying to get only mfee_id

Comment: Well, it gives an error message," Call to a member function get() on integer"

Answer (score 0):

You need to do a groupBy -

```
$sfees = sfee::where('student_id', '=',$sid)->groupBy('student_id')->get();
```

**UPDATE**

Try something like this -

```
$sfees = sfee::where('student_id', '=',$sid)->lists('mfee_id');
```

Or you can use the Schema Builder like this -

```
DB::table('sfees')->where('student_id', '=', $id)->lists('mfee_id');
```

Comment: It is still showing only one result. I have updated my question and added structure of my table i am trying to retrieve. Could you look at that?